# Sending email with silent Subject

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to send silent subject in email that can not be modified by the sender?

```
<div class="col-md-11">
 <a href="mailto:support@support.com?subject=Subject 
          For Email&body=This email is from person or unknown user">E-mail
 </a>
 <p>
    <small>If you have questions, please send requests 
           via e-mail to support team: 
    <a href="mailto:support@support.com?subject=Subject For 
       Email&body=This email is from person or unknown user">
       support@support.com
    </a>
    </small>
 </p>
</div>

href="mailto:support@support.com?subject=Subject For 
      Email&body=This email is from person or unknown user"
```

this will give me the mail to in email field and subject in subject field and even text in body but I wonder about the silent subject in the email.

Comment: You have to use TextArea for email text and send from Server Side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email structure is described in [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822).

There is no such thing as "silent subject" in email fields, so you can use only usual subject field.

`mailto` URI scheme forces your link to be opened as email in default mail client on user's computer. And there is no "universal" way to prevent any mail client from changing that field.

So you can't send your mails in the way you've described.

Comment: maybe I could know the sender beforehand and compare it with incoming email? steal or add to sender some package?